# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controllers

What does this error pertain to? I can't figure out where it the code is incorrect?

Users
Index.html.erb

```
<%= @events.all.each do |event| %>
  <%= if current_user.activities.include?(event.activity) %>
    <%= event.activity %>
    <%= event.description %>
    <%= event.start_time %>
    <%= event.end_time %>
    <%= event.num_attendees_requested %>
    <%= event.location_name %>
    <%= event.street_address %>
    <%= event.city %>
    <%= event.state %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @activities = Activity.all
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @events = Event.all
    @activities = Activity.all
  end
```

Comment: You should use `<%` instead of `<%=` before `@events.all.each do |event|`, but it's won't help you with syntax error. You should post error backtrace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= if current_user.activities.include?(event.activity) %>
```

to

```
<% if current_user.activities.include?(event.activity) %>
```

Comment: thats ok, `<%= @events ... %>` to `<%  @events ... %>` in the first line as well.